# Can you place a Button in front of a VBox in JavaFx?

Tags: java, button, javafx, vbox

Currently I'm working  together with a  collegue  on a contact app.

The contacts are displayed in a ScrollPane that contains a VBox. This VBox contains a Button for each contact to represent a list of contacts.

Our goal is to add a  Button to create new contacts in front of the VBox.

We referenced this picture from android and try do repoduce it : [image: Android contact app]

You can see on the picure that there is a button  to create new contacts in front of the contact list.

Our project currently looks like this: [image: Project screenshot]

Is there any way to put a button in front of our  VBox to get the same result?

Comment: Yes, you can use a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) as the root layout and then put your `VBox` and the `Button` for creating a new contact into it.

Answer (score 0):

Like anko mentioned
in the comments  it works with a StackPane as root.

Comment: glad that's a solution for you :) Nevertheless: next stop tutorial on layouts